# Highlighting code in Github

Tags: css, github, markdown

I write codes at a GitHub page and I want to highlight my codes in it. I know that Github provides default code highlighting but my problem is this: Operator colors are always black and this is a problem when I use a dark theme. I mean:

[image]

I use highlight.js. Why that operators are always black? I tried

```
code { color: white;
}
```

in a CSS file but it did not work.

Comment: Try installing Stylish plugin for Chrome. It already has pre-configured user-defined sheets and you can customize it in every way.

Comment: @Niloct, the OP wants to _write_ posts such that they display in a particular way. Requiring all _readers_ to install a browser plugin is a poor solution.

Comment: He says I use a dark theme, so it's for his use only.

Comment: Thanks everybody. I found it: Wrote .highlight .o {color: White; } into the CSS file. Here is Github's default file: https://gist.github.com/demisx/025698a7b5e314a7a4b5